# In this headline "received" is a verb or an adjective?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

the headline is:

"Jeff Pash discussed a cheerleading scandal, brokered penalties and received perks in emails with the former president of the Washington Football Team."

it seems to me that "received" can be seen as either a verb or an adjective, although it sounds more like an adjective describing perks as all perks already received. In the "and received perks......" part, could the "and" not be part of a list any more?

Comment: The specific text here is structurally ambiguous. On one reading, Pash discussed all the three things (a cheerleading scandal, the brokering of penalties and the receiving of perks) ***in emails***. In that reading, ***received*** is used adjectivally. In the other reading (where ***received*** is a verb), the qualifier ***in emails*** only applies to those perks (the actual discussions may have been *in person*, or *by telephone*; that's unstated). Knowledge of English doesn't help you decide which of those two interpretations is most likely - it's entirely a matter of "common sense".

Answer (score -1):

It is a verb in this context. It's a little confusing but the direction of action is towards the speaker so the passive voice would actually be towards the objected that is being received.

Received as an adjective is not standard at all, perhaps used in sentences like "The received letters were laden with neurotoxins" but the more idiomatic way would be "The letters, which had been received, were laden with neurotoxins".